# Duplex default in Acrobat X

Tags: pdf, printing

My MacOS and Acrobat Pro version are as follows.
Mac OS X 10.7.5
Acrobat 10.1.6

When I'm printing PDF documents, I can never set 'duplex printing' as a default setting.
I think I could do it in previous versions.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to Acrobat XI if you can. I've found it's so much better than X in so many ways that it was totally worth the price. I'm not at my Mac now, but you should be able to set the profile you want in either the `Print` or `Print Setup` dialog, then save it as a default.